# Надо вычислить среднее арифметическое массива из 5 чисел. Кто может подсказать в чем ошибка и пути ее решения?)

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите 5 чисел");
        int M[] = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
        M[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        double a = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
        a =+ M[i];
        }
        double  b = a / M.length;
        System.out.println("Среднее арифметическое:" + " " + b);
        }
        }
```

Comment: А что значит `a =+ M[i];` ?
Вообще, странно, что компилятор не делает подсказки о возможных опечатках такого типа... Или делает?

Comment: Я хочу посчитать сумму всех элементов в массиве

Comment: Ну, а вы ничего не перепутали в этой строке?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка здесь:

```
a =+ M[i];
```

Исправьте на это, и все заработает:

```
 a += M[i];
```

Оффтоп:
Поправил ваш код, некоторые элементы здесь не нужны:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите 5 чисел");
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        a += s.nextInt();
    }
    double  b = a / 5;
    System.out.println("Среднее арифметическое:" + " " + b);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) Моя вина, перепутал

Comment: Посмотрите, что я убрал из вашего кода. Если понятно, почему я что-то убрал, просто примите ответ.